# Multiple covariates as treatment in double ML

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, treatment-effect, causal-diagram

I have multiple economic indicators as covariates such as employment rate, gdp growth, average wage, etc. I want to estimate each of them's effect on travel demand. I was thinking of two steps:

1. Make a DAG based on their relationships
2. Make each of the economic indicators one at a time as treatment variable and the rest as covariates and get the treatment effect using the DAG and Double ML

Does this makes sense or not?

Comment: Yes, but correct for multiple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Can you elaborate on why do I need to correct for multiple comparisons?

Comment: That "one at a time as treatment" means you inflate your chance of finding something significant.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. Thanks